# Refactoring the following LINQ query to perform better and look more simple

Tags: c#, linq

Consider a function (GetData) which returns the following result set where the first column is division id and the second one is "TotalSales":

```
DivisionID: 3     500
DivisionID: 3     500
DivisionID: 3     500

DivisionID: 4     800     
DivisionID: 4     800

DivisionID: 5     50
```

I need to write a LINQ query to get the following result:

```
DiviosnID 3: (500 * 3) - 500 = 1000
DiviosnID 4: (800 * 2) - 800 = 800
DiviosnID 5: 0 /*this since it's happening only once*/
```

So the total becomes: 1000 + 800 = 1800

Finally, this value should be multiplied by -1, which results in -1800.

The following LINQ query gets the job done, however, it's IMSHO scary. The question is that whether it can be re-written to perform faster and look nicer?! Please note there's a third column there, just like the TotalSales named "TotalPurchases" which I need to do the same calculation for.

```
GetData()
.Where(t => t.DivisionId != 0)
.GroupBy(t => t.DivisionId)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.Select(g => new MyEntity
{
    TotalSales = g.Sum(n => n.TotalSales) - (g.Sum(n => n.TotalSales) / g.Count()),
    TotalPurchases = g.Sum(n => n.TotalPurchases) - (g.Sum(n => n.TotalPurchases) / g.Count())
})
.Union(Enumerable.Repeat(new MyEntity(), 1))
.Aggregate((t1, t2) => new MyEntity
{
    TotalSales = -(t1.TotalSales + t2.TotalSales),
    TotalPurchases = -(t1.TotalPurchases + t2.TotalPurchases),
});
```

Thank you

Comment: What are the rules? Is `TotalSales` always the same for each record with same `DivisionID`? How result should be calculated? Equation in your example is different from this obtained from query (`TotalSales*(COUNT-1)` vs `SUM(TotalSales) - AVG(TotalSales)`

Comment: I assumed taking the code as the example, so I went with SUM(TotalSales) - AVG(TotalSales).

Comment: Also something is wrong with `Aggregate` call. For odd groups number result will be >0, but for even it will be <0.

Comment: @Lolo Yes, TotalSales is always the same for each record (based on DivisionID). But honestly, I don't get how it those two equations aren't equal. TotalSales * (Count-1)  results in the same answer that SUM(TotalSales) - AVG(TotalSales) produces. Would you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @JoeBank It wasn't clearly said, that "TotalSales" is always the same for same DivisionId, and keeping that in mind it is obviously not equal. For example, for TotalSales values [300, 300, 200] you will get from firs equation 600 or 400 depending on order, and 533 from second.
You can simplify `Select` to `TotalSales = g.Skip(1).Sum(n => n.TotalSales)` with that condition in mind. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I can't believe how the new answer is simplified & how I overcomplicated things. That was very clever, thank you @Lolo. I love the skip(1).sum(the rest) idea. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposition:

```
var result = data
    .Where(t => t.DivisionID != 0)
    .GroupBy(t => t.DivisionID)
    .Select(g => new MyEntity
    {
        TotalSales = g.Sum(n => n.TotalSales) - g.Average(n => n.TotalSales),
        TotalPurchases = g.Sum(n => n.TotalPurchases) - g.Average(n => n.TotalPurchases)
    })
    .Aggregate(new MyEntity(), (t1, t2) => new MyEntity
    {
        TotalSales = t1.TotalSales - t2.TotalSales,
        TotalPurchases = t1.TotalPurchases - t2.TotalPurchases,
    });
```

Checking for `Where(g => g.Count() > 1)` is not necessary, because SUM and AVG for 1 element group is equal, so select will return 0.
I also removed `Union(Enumerable.Repeat(new MyEntity(), 1))` and I added `seed` to aggregate call - this is start value.

Another one:

```
var result = data
    .Where(t => t.DivisionID != 0)
    .GroupBy(t => t.DivisionID)
    .Select(g => new MyEntity
    {
        TotalSales = g.Sum(n => n.TotalSales) - g.Average(n => n.TotalSales),
        TotalPurchases = g.Sum(n => n.TotalPurchases) - g.Average(n => n.TotalPurchases)
    })
    .GroupBy(t => 0) // create single group
    .Select(g => new MyEntity
    {
        TotalSales = -g.Sum(t => t.TotalSales),
        TotalPurchases = -g.Sum(t => t.TotalPurchases)
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Assuming that `TotalSales` is constant for `DivisionId` you can use that:

```
var result = data
    .Where(t => t.DivisionID != 0)
    .GroupBy(t => t.DivisionID)
    .Select(g => new MyEntity
    {
        TotalSales = g.Skip(1).Sum(n => n.TotalSales),
        TotalPurchases = g.Skip(1).Sum(n => n.TotalPurchases)
    })
    .Aggregate(new MyEntity(), (t1, t2) => new MyEntity
    {
        TotalSales = t1.TotalSales - t2.TotalSales,
        TotalPurchases = t1.TotalPurchases - t2.TotalPurchases,
    });

var result = data
    .Where(t => t.DivisionID != 0)
    .GroupBy(t => t.DivisionID)
    .Select(g => new MyEntity
    {
        TotalSales = g.Skip(1).Sum(n => n.TotalSales),
        TotalPurchases = g.Skip(1).Sum(n => n.TotalPurchases)
    })
    .GroupBy(t => 0) // create single group
    .Select(g => new MyEntity
    {
        TotalSales = -g.Sum(t => t.TotalSales),
        TotalPurchases = -g.Sum(t => t.TotalPurchases)
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick first attempt:

```
var consolidatedData = GetData()
        .GroupBy(t => t.DivisionId)
        .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any(i => i.DivisionId != 0))
        .Select(g => new
        {
            TotalSales = -(g.Sum(n => n.TotalSales) - g.Average(n => n.TotalSales)),
            TotalPurchases = -(g.Sum(n => n.TotalPurchases) - g.Average(n => n.TotalPurchases))
        });

var overallSales = consolidatedData.Sum(i => i.TotalSales);
var overallPurchases = consolidatedData.Sum(i => i.TotalPurchases);
```

Using Skip, you avoid the potentially expensive Count() being run on every group - it just Skips one item, and sees if there's anything left.

By building the result into an IEnumerable of anonyomous objects, the code is simplified - you can then query it afterewards when you want the final sums. Note that Average is also used in place of Sum / Count.

The Aggregate is removed - you only compute the final sum at the end when you need it.